# Code to run that can help benchmark a new SAS drive?

Tags: sas, performance-testing, benchmarking

We just got a new Server at work that will be used only for running SAS code, and I've been asked to run some tests and make sure that it's performing better than our other servers. I'm not an expert at this so I want to make sure I avoid making naive mistakes that don't properly measure the performance of the server. My header looks like this:

```
options fullstimer;
%LET BenchStartTime =  %sysfunc(datetime(),22.);
```

Which I use as a check for the "real time" report in the log. I have a vague understanding of the difference between "user cpu time" and "system cpu time", but if anyone wants to offer up additional information on that, that would be helpful.

Anyway, the main point of this post is that I want to know if there are any standard benchmark tests that I should be using in order to see if this new server is better than the old ones. Currently I'm using something I found online which is just appending a bunch of copies of sashelp.class (but I think this might be a bad idea because pulling from the C: and loading it into a different drive might be the same across all servers, right? If the C: is the slowest drive, doesn't that become the bottleneck?), and I'm also using code that basically generates a bunch of random data of a fixed size and comparing runtimes. Is this the correct approach? Is there something else I should be doing? How many times should I be running these benchmark tests to make sure that it isn't a fluke?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What kind of work do you normally do?

Comment: Data analysis in a consulting capacity. Mostly loading files (majority are CSVs), cleaning, merging, transposing, proc meansing, etc.

Comment: Ok, what sort of job did you (or they) have in mind when deciding to upgrade?  What's the slow boat right now?

Comment: The slow jobs are usually the giant merges, but the real issue is that we have 40-50 users on the server during the day and if enough people are doing medium sized jobs, programs take way longer

Comment: Our current processes use the following: At beginning of code data benchmark; start=datetime();run; And same at the end. data benchmark; set benchmark end=datetime();run; Then these are stored to history dataset.

Answer (score 2):

I would test by doing the things that you normally do.  If you run larger merges, then you're basically talking I/O; so just make a very large dataset, write it out, read it in, etc., and perform the same test on the other machine.  Perform each test a few times each in a fresh SAS session.

Further, it sounds like you need to make sure the new server can handle multiple concurrent sessions.  You can simulate this in part by submitting many connections from one computer by using SAS/CONNECT; that allows you to start multiple concurrent sessions.  Then do so, perhaps I would create a script that starts a local SAS session, signs on to the server and rsubmits a job of a normal difficulty that takes maybe 5 to 10 minutes, and then run that script 20 times concurrently (you can script this or just double click a .bat file 20 times).  See how it handles it as compared to the other server.

Answer (score 0):

On SAS 9.2 and later you can use the %SASHOME%/SASFoundation/9.x/sasiotest.exe utility. You will find some further Guidance in Support note [51659](http://support.sas.com/kb/51/659.html).

*Edit:*

A similiar utility can be downloaded for Unix Plattform, details in Support note [51660](https://support.sas.com/kb/51/660.html).